# How to change the default calling convention in MinGW gcc

Tags: mingw, mingw32

In Microsoft Visual C++, the default calling convention can be set to stdcall using /Gz compiler option. How to do this in MinGW g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a great way to go about shooting yourself in the foot; better, IMO, to leave the default unequivocally as `__cdecl`, and declare `__stdcall` functions explicitly, so there is no potential for confusion.  However, if you are determined to do this, a good place to start would be reading the GCC online documentation; try googling for "gcc manual", which should take you [(e.g.) here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=gcc+manual&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=lwv8VaqtEIn6aqG_qvgP).

Make sure to select the version of the manual which matches your GCC version, then consult the section on "Function Attributes"; this should point you to the `-mrtd` option as a likely candidate for what you want to do. Look this up in the options index, and follow the reference to see something like:

> -mrtd
>
> Use a different function-calling convention, in which functions
>   that take a fixed number of arguments return with the ret num
>   instruction, which pops their arguments while returning. This saves
>   one instruction in the caller since there is no need to pop the
>   arguments there.
>
> You can specify that an individual function is called with this calling sequence with the function attribute ‘stdcall’. You can also
>   override the -mrtd option by using the function attribute ‘cdecl’. See
>   Function Attributes.
>
> Warning: this calling convention is incompatible with the one normally used on Unix, so you cannot use it if you need to call
>   libraries compiled with the Unix compiler.
>
> Also, you must provide function prototypes for all functions that take variable numbers of arguments (including printf); otherwise
>   incorrect code is generated for calls to those functions.
>
> In addition, seriously incorrect code results if you call a function with too many arguments. (Normally, extra arguments are
>   harmlessly ignored.)